# Spring Boot postgresql embedded tomcat fails to start

Tags: database, postgresql, spring-security, spring-data, spring-boot

I've set up a Spring Boot starter application.  Now switching from embedded db to postgreSQL using properties example from docs and guessing on the dependencies.  With setup below, embedded tomcat server fails to launch.

Grateful for any advice.

gradle build

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url "http://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot" }
        mavenLocal()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.0.1.RELEASE")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'spring-boot'
//apply plugin: 'jetty'
//apply plugin: 'war'


jar {
    baseName = 'base-app'
    version =  '0.1.0'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "http://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot" }
    maven { url "https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases" }
}


configurations {
    providedRuntime
}

dependencies {
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web") {
    }
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security")
    compile("org.thymeleaf:thymeleaf-spring4")
    testCompile("junit:junit")


    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc")
    compile("org.postgresql:postgresql:9.2-1004-jdbc4")
    compile("org.hibernate:hibernate-validator")
    compile('org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:4.0.1.Final')
    compile("org.springframework:spring-tx")

}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '1.11'
}
```

application.properties

```
spring.thymeleaf.cache=false
server.port=9500
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/testdb
spring.datasource.username=testdb
spring.datasource.password=testdb
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
```

error log

```
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:188)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1123)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:799)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    ... 6 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'springSecurityFilterChain' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/WebSecurityConfiguration.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public javax.servlet.Filter org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration.springSecurityFilterChain() throws java.lang.Exception] threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptStatementFailedException: Failed to execute SQL script statement at line 1 of resource class path resource [org/springframework/security/core/userdetails/jdbc/users.ddl]: create table users(username varchar_ignorecase(50) not null primary key,password varchar_ignorecase(500) not null,enabled boolean not null); nested exception is org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: type "varchar_ignorecase" does not exist
  Position: 29
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:597)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1094)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:989)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.getOrderedBeansOfType(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:367)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.getServletContextInitializerBeans(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:268)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext$1.onStartup(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:213)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.ServletContextInitializerLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent(ServletContextInitializerLifecycleListener.java:54)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5355)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 6 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public javax.servlet.Filter org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration.springSecurityFilterChain() throws java.lang.Exception] threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptStatementFailedException: Failed to execute SQL script statement at line 1 of resource class path resource [org/springframework/security/core/userdetails/jdbc/users.ddl]: create table users(username varchar_ignorecase(50) not null primary key,password varchar_ignorecase(500) not null,enabled boolean not null); nested exception is org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: type "varchar_ignorecase" does not exist
  Position: 29
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:188)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:586)
    ... 22 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptStatementFailedException: Failed to execute SQL script statement at line 1 of resource class path resource [org/springframework/security/core/userdetails/jdbc/users.ddl]: create table users(username varchar_ignorecase(50) not null primary key,password varchar_ignorecase(500) not null,enabled boolean not null); nested exception is org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: type "varchar_ignorecase" does not exist
  Position: 29
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils.executeSqlScript(ScriptUtils.java:458)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ResourceDatabasePopulator.populate(ResourceDatabasePopulator.java:206)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.DatabasePopulatorUtils.execute(DatabasePopulatorUtils.java:49)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.DataSourceInitializer.execute(DataSourceInitializer.java:108)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.DataSourceInitializer.afterPropertiesSet(DataSourceInitializer.java:93)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configurers.provisioning.JdbcUserDetailsManagerConfigurer.initUserDetailsService(JdbcUserDetailsManagerConfigurer.java:160)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configurers.userdetails.UserDetailsServiceConfigurer.configure(UserDetailsServiceConfigurer.java:48)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configurers.userdetails.UserDetailsServiceConfigurer.configure(UserDetailsServiceConfigurer.java:33)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.configure(AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.java:378)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.doBuild(AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.java:327)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractSecurityBuilder.build(AbstractSecurityBuilder.java:39)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.authenticationManager(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:231)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.getHttp(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:171)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.init(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:276)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.init(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:61)
    at com.qbmetrics.baseapp.config.WebSecurityConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$4b30fbc7.init(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.init(AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.java:369)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.doBuild(AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.java:322)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractSecurityBuilder.build(AbstractSecurityBuilder.java:39)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration.springSecurityFilterChain(WebSecurityConfiguration.java:92)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$e1d58644.CGLIB$springSecurityFilterChain$4(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$e1d58644$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$98399566.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:312)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$e1d58644.springSecurityFilterChain(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:166)
    ... 23 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: type "varchar_ignorecase" does not exist
  Position: 29
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2157)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1886)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:255)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.execute(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:559)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeWithFlags(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:403)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.execute(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:395)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils.executeSqlScript(ScriptUtils.java:443)
    ... 52 common frames omitted
```

Comment: There should be more errors logged in the console

Comment: geoand: you're right. I added the beginning.  Seems to point to security config

Comment: Could you also show your datasource configuration?

Comment: solved.  withDefaultSchema(); option must be deactivated with production db.

Comment: i tried with .withDefaultSchema(); and didn't work... this solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24174884/spring-security-jdbcauthentication-default-scheme-error-on-postgresql worked for me

Answer (score 2):

In the stack it says what the error is: you're using an invalid data type for your Users table:

> nested exception is org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: type "varchar_ignorecase" does not exist

Happens when you try to run this:

```sql
create table users(username varchar_ignorecase(50) not null primary key,password varchar_ignorecase(500) not null,enabled boolean not null);
```

The list of valid data types is here: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/datatype.html

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error described, this has been solved in the link [spring boot  security using jdbcauthentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24174884/spring-security-jdbc-authentication-default-schema-error-when-using-postgresql).

Cause :
So when the application starts up, it executes a create schema sql command (because you added "withDefaultSchema" in your security configuration) which contains 'varchar_ignorecase' in the sql command/query but varchar_ignorecase is not recognised by postgresql or even mysql as a datatype as a result, it is failing.

Solution : 
Make modification according to the answer on the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24174884/spring-security-jdbc-authentication-default-schema-error-when-using-postgresql).