# Spring Security JDBC authentication default schema error when using PostgreSQL

Tags: spring, spring-security, postgresql-9.1

Is it really impossible to use *default schema* for Spring Security with PostgreSQL, because the part `"varchar_ignorecase" does not exist` can't be replaced?

I'm just testing the default settings:

```
auth.jdbcAuthentication()
            .dataSource(dataSource)
            .withDefaultSchema();
```

And below is the error:

> Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException:
>   Factory method [public javax.servlet.Filter
>   org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration.springSecurityFilterChain()
>   throws java.lang.Exception] threw exception;
>
> nested exception is
>   org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptStatementFailedException:
>   Failed to execute SQL script statement at line 1 of resource class
>   path resource
>   [org/springframework/security/core/userdetails/jdbc/users.ddl]: create
>   table users(username varchar_ignorecase(50) not null primary
>   key,password varchar_ignorecase(500) not null,enabled boolean not
>   null);
>
> nested exception is
>   org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR:
>   type "varchar_ignorecase" does not exist

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Cause the default schema is not suitable for PostgreSQL, I need to create my own schema and implement own query for user and authority query.

```
auth.jdbcAuthentication()
                .dataSource(dataSource)
                .usersByUsernameQuery(
                        "select username,password, enabled from users where username=?")
                .authoritiesByUsernameQuery(
                        "select username, role from user_roles where username=?");
```

Comment: Why the schema is "not suitable" for PostgreSQL and MySQL? BTW, it's working... tks

Comment: @Hinotori The default schema (per http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/appendix-schema.html) is written in a SQL dialect for HSQLDB (particularly, PostgreSQL does not have the 'varchar_ignorecase' type which is present in the default user schema). Users of other databases need to translate that to something which works. See the documentation on initializing a database with Spring JDBC here, it has some excellent tips: http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-database-initialization.html#howto-initialize-a-database-using-spring-jdbc

Comment: I've done as this says and it still executes the ddl.

Comment: To avoid the `dll` execution you must remove the `withDefaultSchema()` sentence

Comment: @ManuelJordan It's after midnight here... I've spent 4 hours today on this. Thank you for your comment!

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to adding withDefaultSchema(). simply define your schema.sql and data.sql with proper column names and foreign key constraints. Following is the example configuration for Mysql (in the Spring Boot).

schema.sql

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS users;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS authorities;

CREATE TABLE users
(
   username VARCHAR(50)  NOT NULL,
   password VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
   enabled  TINYINT      NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
   PRIMARY KEY (username)
 );

CREATE TABLE authorities
(
username  VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
authority VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
FOREIGN KEY (username) REFERENCES users (username)
);
```

Then define users and authorities (data.sql)

```
INSERT INTO users (username, password, enabled)
values ('user','pass',1);

INSERT INTO authorities (username, authority)
values ('user', 'ROLE_USER');
```

finally, define the authentication mechanism

```
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth
            .jdbcAuthentication()
            .passwordEncoder(NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance())
            .dataSource(dataSource);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Schema for PGSQL:

schema.sql

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS users;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS authorities;

CREATE TABLE users
(
username VARCHAR(50)  NOT NULL,
password VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
enabled  INT      NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
PRIMARY KEY (username)
);

CREATE TABLE authorities
(
username  VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
authority VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
FOREIGN KEY (username) REFERENCES users (username)
);
```

User injection on data.sql

```
INSERT INTO users (username, password, enabled)
values ('user','pass',1);

INSERT INTO authorities (username, authority)
values ('user', 'ROLE_USER');
```

Thanks to Mr.Q. I totally used your MySQL schema and adapted it for PGSQL.